# Batch Script not Releasing after Execution

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script which performs file version controlling after a Backup event has taken place. This batch script, writing to a normal txt logfile, calls a PowerShell script to send this Logfile as an attachment with a success notification email. I have managed to release the writing lock on the log file, to allow PS to attach and send the file, but the Batch script does not stop after the entire sequence has been completed.

When I check the log file, I see that the shell instance has placed a 'Pause' in the script, instead of a self-termination (as it is instructed), and results in:

1. `Press any key to continue...` with a waiting shell
2. an app locked logfile, which won't allow the script to run again, unless the logfile is released.

**This is the sequence of events:**
[image: Script Sequence]
The only Pause I have, is in < bak_send_exec.bat > - its sole purpose is to start a PS script:

```
PowerShell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass
```

If I remove it, the PS does not start. If I have it in there, the PS starts and executes flawlessly, but the logfile stays locked in a shell instances which is in Paused state, until someone kills the cmd.exe instances which locked the file.

This runs on a weekend at 01:00 am, so user intervention should not be required.

**VC Script Summary:**

---

This inter-connected batch files renames two identical files (in different locations) with timestamps. The timestamp is written to a variable for use in a notification email, which is sent using a PowerShell command. The entire process is logged to a txt log file (file overwritten when script runs again), and the log file is included with a Notification Email, mentioned earlier.

**Script Calls:**

---

**Initial Start Command:** Triggers the Version Control Procedures and Logs Progress with `versioncontrol_post.bat > TSLog.txt 2>&1`

**versioncontrol_post.bat:** Performs main procedure, then ends with `CALL bak_send_exec.bat`

**bak_send_exec.bat:** The suspected cause... Coding of entire file is three lines long, but required as mentioned earlier, for policy relaxation:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file bak_send.ps1
PAUSE
```

**bak_send.ps1:** Performs main procedure to make a copy of the temporary log (TSLog.txt) to its final home, releases the TSLog file to work with the new duplicate of it, and continues to take that new duplicate and attach it to an email and sends email. The final line in the procedure is `EXIT`.

---

Fault finding tells me that the issue is not with the PowerShell script, but rather with the script that calls it. Taking out the PAUSE command results in the PowerShell not starting.

Does anyone have a possible solution to this *"feature"*?

Comment: Where is the code you need help with?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Updated with the call and termination code. The main procedures aren't important here.

Comment: [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) instead of [pause](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html)?

Comment: Stephan is correct, you add a pause, so the pause holds the process open file open, instead try with `timeout` and see if that helps resolve the issue. you can also try and `start "" PowerShell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file bak_send.ps1` to start powershell script in a new instance, let it do it's thing and exit, which will hold your pause in the original script.